# How to target last 3 elements in a container using CSS :nth-last-child(n)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using only CSS. How do you target the last 3 elements in a container? I'm using `:nth-last-child(n)`, but was wondering if there was a way to limit it to a set of elements to target only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean the last three children:

```
:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
    color: coral;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UHv8u/4/

Comment: yep, thats it! more info here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to hard-code it.. the `css`

```
p:nth-last-child(1),p:nth-last-child(2),p:nth-last-child(3){ //assuming all are p tags
background:blue;
}
```